# Error update sql statement in access database [VB2010]

Tags: vb.net

My Update code is not working. when i run this, an error show in this line **str = "Update Table1 set Mining Allowance='" & Mining_AllowanceTextBox.Text & "' ,Basic = '" & BasicTextBox.Text & "',Accomodation = " & AccomodationTextBox.Text & " WHERE ID =" & IDTextBox & ""**. Error message is     **Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'.**
Below is my code. Pls solve this error.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Salary_Classification
    Dim provider As String
    Dim datafile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection


     Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
            provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
            datafile = "F:\EmployeeTB.mdb"
            connString = provider & datafile
            myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
            myConnection.Open()
            Dim str As String
            str = "Update Table1 set Mining Allowance='" & Mining_AllowanceTextBox.Text & "' ,Basic = '" & BasicTextBox.Text & "',Accomodation = " & AccomodationTextBox.Text & " WHERE ID =" & IDTextBox & ""
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

            Try
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Dispose()
                myConnection.Close()
                IDTextBox.Clear()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Stop trying to concatenate your SQL. It's error prone and exposes you to SQL injection. Google *parameterized queries vb.net*.

Comment: If you have a space (" ") in the column name, you need to wrap the name with square brackets. i.e.:  `[Mining Allowance]`

Comment: Don't work. pls help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the data types of each of the fields and adjust any of the OleDbType parameters to the correct data type. The Using statements will close and dispose of your objects even it there is an error.

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        Using myConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\EmployeeTB.mdb")
            Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Update Table1 set Mining Allowance=?,Basic = ?,Accomodation = ? WHERE ID =?;", myConnection)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@MiningAllowance", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Mining_AllowanceTextBox.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Basic", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = BasicTextBox.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Accomodation", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = AccomodationTextBox.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IDTextBox.Text
                Try
                    myConnection.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    myConnection.Close()
                    IDTextBox.Clear()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please accept it as the answer with the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. Glad it is working.